# Silent creation of a pdf file from angular 7 through electron

Tags: angular, electron, jspdf

I am working on a little cross-platform software. Currently, I am using:
Angular cli 7, electron packager and a backend in Java Spring.
In particular, I need to create a pdf file starting by angular side (I am using jspdf). My goal is to avoid the OS request of the location in which the file will be saved (for example, if I use .save() function of jspdf from angular), but I have all the information that will fill the pdf file in an angular specific page. For completeness, I'll post what I am trying without any success.

Here is my main.js file:

```
 const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
 const fs = require('fs');
 const os = require('os');
 const path = require('path');
 const electron = require('electron');
 const ipc = electron.ipcMain;
 const shell = electron.shell; 

 let win;

 

 ipc.on('print-to-pdf', function (event, file) {
 const dir = 'C:\\Users\\GMC\\Desktop\\salvataggi';
 const pdfPath = path.join(dir, 'a4.pdf');



 fs.writeFile(pdfPath, file, function (err) {
  if (err) {
    throw err
  }
  shell.openExternal('file://' + pdfPath)
  event.sender.send('wrote-pdf', pdfPath)
 });
 });
```

Into my angular component there is a button that calls the function:

```
 // Just the relevant imports
 import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
 import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';

  anteprimaBolla(){
  var doc = new jsPDF();
  doc.text('Hello world!', 10, 10);

  //  doc.save('C:\\Users\\GMC\\Desktop\\salvataggi\\a4.pdf')
  this._electronService.ipcRenderer.send('print-to-pdf',doc.output('blob'));

this._electronService.ipcRenderer.on('wrote-pdf', pdfPath => {
  this._electronService.shell.openItem(pdfPath);
});
```

So, in a few words, I am trying to pass a pdf file from angular to electron side (channel print-to-pdf), save it with electron and then show it again with angular. I think that to save in a silent modality I need to pass through electron (if I am wrong, and I am hoping that, I think it could became a lot easier)

Is there some way to silent save from angular or, in alternative, to pass a pdf file from angular to electron?